# Actual bash string storing awk source

Tags: bash, awk

I have been calling awk commands from bash using the customary single quotes.
How can one use an actual string to store the awk source, then introduce that to tho awk command later?

```
printf '%s\n' "$@"  \
  | awk -v frg="$ctp" -v rst="$sgr" -v prl="$rl"  \
    '{ if ( $0 ~ prl ) {
         fm = "%s%s%s\n" ; printf(fm, frg, $0, rst) }
       else {
         fm = "%s\n" ; printf(fm, $0) }
     }'
```

The change would be

```
str="
{ if ( $0 ~ prl ) {
    fm = "%s%s%s\n" ; printf(fm, frg, $0, rst) }
  else {
    fm = "%s\n" ; printf(fm, $0)
   }
}"
```

Then I would perhaps call the command with

```
printf '%s\n' "$@"  \
  | awk -v frg="$ctp" -v rst="$sgr" -v prl="$rl" "$str"
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You already used single quotes in the first command so why not `str='...'`?

Comment: Why would you do something like that? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you're asking for help to implement what sounds like a bad solution to some so-far unspecified problem. If you [edit] your question to explain (with a [mcve]) the problem you're trying to solve then maybe what you're trying to do would make sense or maybe we could suggest better alternatives.

Comment: I will explain.  I have need to use the same code at other places within the same file, and do not want to have multiple copies of the same awk block.

Comment: @konsolebox You are right.  Because if I use double quotes variable expansion would occur.

Comment: the current assignment (to `str`) has an issue in that the 'internal' double quotes are not escaped, which means you'll likely generate syntax errors when running `awk "$str"`

Comment: @Avacha [that's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75704641/actual-bash-string-storing-awk-source/75705002?noredirect=1#comment133554723_75704641) what functions are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more info on the problem you're trying to solve - don't store code in a string, use a function:

```
foo() {
  awk -v frg="$ctp" -v rst="$sgr" -v prl="$rl"  \
    '{ if ( $0 ~ prl ) {
         fm = "%s%s%s\n" ; printf(fm, frg, $0, rst) }
       else {
         fm = "%s\n" ; printf(fm, $0) }
     }'
}

printf '%s\n' "$@"  \
  | foo
```

or:

```
foo() {
  awk -v frg="$1" -v rst="$2" -v prl="$3"  \
    '{ if ( $0 ~ prl ) {
         fm = "%s%s%s\n" ; printf(fm, frg, $0, rst) }
       else {
         fm = "%s\n" ; printf(fm, $0) }
     }'
}

printf '%s\n' "$@"  \
  | foo "$ctp" "$sgr" "$rl"
```

or similar.

That way you encapsulate the functionality you want from your awk script while avoiding tightly coupling your shell script to your awk script.

Comment: I like the last implementation.  Can one use foo in the following manner: `foo "$ctp" "$sgr" "$rl" < <(printf "%s\n" "$@")`

Comment: Yes, just try it.

Comment: My whole idea is to have the ability to run the same code in multiple different ways:  Through printf, cat, redirection, ... But without have multiple instances of the awk block.

Comment: That's what functions are for.

Comment: What I have done in the past was to put all functionality in the function (including user-defined options, ...), rather than the technique you outlined.

Comment: I don't know what that means, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If the objective is to re-use snippets of `awk` code you can do this but you'll need to consider (at least) a few issues:

- when building the strings keep in mind you may need to escape certain characters (eg, `$`, double quotes) when the string is wrapped in double quotes (eg, `str=" {print "hi, "$0}"` should be rewritten as `str="{print \"hi, \"\$0}"` or `str='{print "hi, "$0}'`
- when referencing the variable make sure to wrap the reference in double quotes
- when appending multiple strings make sure there's no space between the quoted references (eg, `awk "$str1" "$str2"` should be rewritten as `awk "$str1""$str2"` or `awk "$str1 $str2"`)

Consider:

```
begin='BEGIN {print "hi"}'                   # or: begin="BEGIN {print \"hi\"}"
end='END {print "bye"}'
inline1='{print "line #",NR,"-",$0}'         # or: inline1="{print \"line#\",NR,\"-\",\$0}"
inline2='{print "input:",$0}'
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ printf "a\nb\n" | awk "$begin""$end"
hi
bye

$ printf "a\nb\n" | awk "$begin $inline1 $end"
hi
line # 1 - a
line # 2 - b
bye

$ printf "a\nb\n" | awk "$begin $inline2 $inline1 $end"
hi
input: a
line # 1 - a
input: b
line # 2 - b
bye
```

If you generate (syntax) errors, or the wrong result, consider running your commands in debug mode (`set -xv`) to see what `bash` (or `awk`) sees, eg:

```
$ set -xv                                        # enable debug mode

$ awk "$begin" "$end"
+ awk 'BEGIN {print "hi"}' 'END {print "bye"}'   # awk only runs the 1st script (ie, the 'BEGIN{}' block)
hi                                               # missing the 'bye'

$ str="BEGIN{print "hi"}"
$ awk "str"
+ str='BEGIN{print hi}'                          # no output because variable "hi" is undefined

$ str="BEGIN{print "hi"}"
$ awk $str                                       # forget to wrap variable reference in double quotes
+ awk 'BEGIN{print' 'hi}'                        # awk will only process 1st (of two) scripts, but 1st script is invalid syntax
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{print
awk: cmd. line:1:            ^ unexpected newline or end of string

$ set +xv                                        # disable debug mode
```

**NOTES:**

- you can use variables to manage snippets of `awk` code but you take on the additional responsibility of understanding the detailed ins-and-outs of how to make it work
- unless you provide detailed comments on said ins-and-outs, chances are other people (who may need to maintain your code) will have problems understanding what's going on and will (likely) break the code

Comment: You provided valuable points in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the objective is to re-use snippets of `awk` code, and you're running `GNU awk`, there is another (and simpler) method ... 'include' files:

- place your code snippets into separate files
- properly define your `AWKPATH` variable
- reference the files via the `@include "<filename>"` construct

Sample script files:

```
$ head begin end inline1 inline2

==> begin <==
BEGIN {print "hi"}

==> end <==
END {print "bye"}

==> inline1 <==
{print "line #",NR,"-",$0}

==> inline2 <==
{print "input:",$0}
```

Define `AWKPATH` variable (assume all files are located under `~/awk_scripts`:

```
$ export AWKPATH="~/awk_scripts"
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
printf "a\nb\n"|awk '
@include "begin"
@include "inline2"; @include "inline1"
@include "end"'
```

This generates:

```
hi
input: a
line # 1 - a
input: b
line # 2 - b
bye
```

To see what `awk` sees (this will *not* run the code; this will (re)format the script) use the `-o-` command line flag, eg:

```
printf "a\nb\n"|awk -o- '
@include "begin"
@include "inline2"; @include "inline1"
@include "end"'

BEGIN {
        print "hi"
}

{
        print "input:", $0
}

{
        print "line #", NR, "-", $0
}

END {
        print "bye"
}

# Included files (-i and/or @include)

# @include "begin"
# @include "inline2"
# @include "inline1"
# @include "end"
```

**NOTE:** for a brief explanation see [Include Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Include-Files.html) and [AWKPATH Variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/AWKPATH-Variable.html)